# Can one class listen to many notifications?

Tags: objective-c

Is it ok that my main class is listen to many notifications ? for example :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(touched:) name:@"touch" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(done:) name:@"touch" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(error:) name:@"touch" object:nil];
```

My main class is listen to many of her child messages . delegates are just too much job so i tried to escape it .

Comment: This can be done, but you really have to weight the cons and benefits of the notification pattern and whether it suits your project. If you have a main class it MAY be that a classic delegate pattern would be better for at least some of those notifications...

Comment: If you know who the receiver is and what messages it responds to, you should use delegation.
Notifications are always delivered in the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the same thread in which an observer registered itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an object can listen to as many notifications as you want. NSNotificationCenter is actually a hash map (in the logical level, not in its implementation). It associates a name of a notification with an object that will handle it, and a selector (the function of the object to respond to the notification). In fact, many operating system functionalities are based on NSNotificationCenter, like the default notifications posted when an application on iOS is entering in the background or comes in the foreground. You can register as many objects as you want in a notification center, for as many callbacks as you want.

However, a more appropriate question is: Would you really want to?

NSNotificationCenter can have multithreading issues, if overused/misused.  Remember that If you base the sender-listener pattern solely on NSNotificationCenter you may find yourself hunting bugs that result in difficult to spot and reproduce crashes. Sure, there is 'addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:' function which allows you to have more control on the thread you want the callback to be called, but in this case unless you start passing the object parameters (the ones that use self.myVar) using '__weak __block' casting, you may have memory leaks. Not to mention that as your program grows, you will have to pay attention to what thread posts the notification, and where it will be handled to avoid multithreading issues. In this case, following all the best practices using NSNotificationCenter can result in messy an not so efficient code.

Speaking on unreadable code, NSNotificationCenter can very easily make your application unmaintainable. Imagine what would happen if you based callback functions solely on that. You would have a spaghetti program, full of callbacks where you wouldn't be able to figure out where they are going to (you would have to do a full text search for each one).

So, if I would be asked to give a simple design consideration, I would say that you should use NSNotificationCenter only when you have a notification in your design that may be answered by zero or more objects that do not need to have any logical correlation with each other, or the object that triggers the notification. For any other case, I recommend looking at the delegate pattern, which Objective C handles so nicely.

I know that this is more than you asked, but I couldn't just respond with a "yes, put as many notification observers  as you want" without discussing the implications of doing so.

By the way, you are registering multiple callbacks under a common name. You should not use a common name for many callbacks in the same class. If you want the same notification to call many functions in the same object, just register the object only once, and in the callback function, call the rest of the functions you want to call.

Comment: ok got it, thanks a lot . i see that somehow many people say bad things on notification ,and wonder why then Apple did that anyway? i use it to let one class(layer/view) passing a message to main view- that some one touched it ..

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is a very important and useful feature. The "bad name" comes from the fact that many devs do not use it properly, and they tend to abuse it, thus creating spaghetti code. Like singletons, which are generally useful, but they are easy to get abused, and create bad code.

Answer (score 0):

A. Is there a copy & paste error? You register three methods of the same observer to the same notification. You can simply register one method that "calls" the other ones. So there is no reason to do, what you want to do.

B. The difference between notifications and delegates is not threading. Both are executed on a foreign thread by default. (You can change this very easily, if you want to, but again for both.)

C. The real difference is that notifications are indirect while delegate messages are directed. A notification sender potentially faces a unknown number of unknown receivers. A delegating object works together with a specific delegate. You can compare this to notifications being (non-interactive) broadcasting TV resp. delegating being an interactive IP-TV. (Okay, this is simplified.) The result is that a delegate can change the behavior of the delegating object while a notification observer (which one?) cannot change the behavior of a notification sender.

If you have a specific partnership of objects in  your design you really should use delegation. More or less work is definitely no reason to change this position. (And I do not see that this is even true.)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. 
You can register for as many notifications as you need to.

Just be sure you remove self from the notification center in dealloc at least.

(You can observe notifications temporarily too, but sounds like you're not there yet)